# Render multiple templates in get_data(request)

Tags: python, django

How to render data on to two templates in `get_data()`?

Generally,

```
def get_data(request):
    data = Model.objects.order_by('id')
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'data':data})
```

.

```
{{for x in data}}
           {{x.model_field}}
    {{end for}}
```

is used to render the stored data from the db into the html file, but how to render the same data into both `'template.html'` and `'template_1.html'`. 
There's no way to pass the templates as a list to my knowledge as read from [django_docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render). Is there any alternate method to it?

Comment: So if you render it, then what?

Comment: @StephenRauch I want to render data into 2 different HTML pages.

Comment: In the same view? Why?

Comment: @IşıkKaplan Other way round, how to get data from two different models and render them to two different html pages in the same view?

Comment: The question is, why do you need 2 rendered html pages inside the same view, instead of asking how to render two html pages in the same view, try asking what you are initially trying to do so we can come up with a more logical solution.

Comment: @IşıkKaplan I have two models defined in the same `models.py`. I want each of the models's data to be displayed in two different html pages

Comment: Am I missing something here? Why don't you create a view for each model instead of trying to render two different templates?

Comment: @IşıkKaplan How do I retrieve data from each model? Please tell how create view for that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#views.py

from django.views.generic import DetailView
from my_app.models import MyModel, MyModel2

class MyView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'my_object'
    template_name = 'templates/model.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        return MyModel.objects.get(pk=pk)


class MyView2(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'my_object'
    template_name = 'templates/model2.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        return MyModel2.objects.get(pk=pk)


# urls.py

from django.urls import re_path
from my_app.views import MyView, MyView2

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^model/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', MyView.as_view()),
    re_path(r'^model2/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', MyView2.as_view()),
]
```

This is a very basic example, `/model/15/` would render `templates/model/` with `MyModel` object that has the pk 15.

In the template you can use `{{ my_object }}` to get the object

Anything you didn't understand, feel free to comment it.